# Feet problem when blending generic animations

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

There’s a problem I’ve noticed when I’m blending generic animations. It is that the feet do not stay in place when blending. Here’s a video: https://www.veed.io/view/fe2d16bf-a15c-416b-bdc0-db5af95da18d?sharingWidget=true&panel=share. If it was a humanoid avatar type, this can be fixed by toggling the “foot ik” check mark in the animatior state. Is there a work around to this for generic? Thanks!!

I haven’t tried anything because I don’t have any ideas on what to do.